# Error when importing QtCore from PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtcore

am getting this error when trying to import `QtCore`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyBytes_FromString
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so
Expected in: flat namespace
     in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to solve this by updating your PyQt5 [(instructions here, although they're currently temporarily offline)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source) and pyqt_tools (which you can do with pip).